# Close Form from Static Method

Tags: c#

How can i close a form instance (it's a singleton) from a static method? It's a fade in/out form that i need to close without effects in some situation based on a bool value in FormClosing Event. The main issue is that when I show a dialog form when this tooltip form is showed at the end of fade out timer both form closes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form is singleton I suggest you to define a private property in your form, containing the instance. This property can be initialized in `OnCreated` event. Using this property you can do whatever you want with your form inside your static methods.